# What does "that chance" refer to?

Tags: everything-everywhere-all-at-once

Waymond is dying in Evelyn's arms:

> Evelyn: What do you mean, you don't see me finish?
>
> Waymond: I'm grateful **that chance** was kind enough to let us have
> these last few moments together.

What does "that chance" refer to?

Comment: Why not consider also joining our [ell.se] site. You may find it helpfull.

Comment: Is interpreting the meaning of English sentences on topic for this site?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you are mistaken to link "that" and "chance" together as "that chance".

It seems to me that the sentence:

> I'm grateful that chance was kind enough to let us have these last few moments together.

Would have the same meaning as the sentence:

"I'm grateful because chance was kind enough to let us have these last few moments together."

Waymond is not specifying "that chance" instead of some other chance.  He is saying he is happy because the workings of chance let them have those last few moments together.

Comment: Yes, clearly the personification of fate,  probably written as "Chance" in the script.

Comment: @Jasen not at all - chance can be personified but I wouldn’t make that the default assumption